# Build object w/ multi dimensional arrays to dynamically create columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

So I wanted to see if someone can lead me in the right direction with this. So I want to build an object with multi dimensional arrays, so I have three main things that need to be grouped: "Categories", "Subheading", "NoSubHeading".

Here is the API response which is `data.d.results`.

I defined it into an object as `var obj = Object.assign({}, data.d.results);`

So I want to build something like this:

```
{
  "Category": {
    "Some Subheading": [
      somepost,
      someotherpost
    ],
    "Some Other Subheading": [
      anotherpost,
      blah
    ],
    "No Subheading": [
      anotherpost,
      blah
    ]
  },
  "Another Category": {
    "Some Subheading": [
      somepost,
      someotherpost
    ],
    "Some Other Subheading": [
      anotherpost,
      blah
    ]
  }
}
```

If someone could lead me in the right direction, all help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While iterating over object use Subheading to define your array:

```
// Initialize output
var result = {};

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

  // Retrieve values
  var cat = obj[i].Category;
  var sub = obj[i].Subheading;

  // Check empty subheading condition
  if (!sub || sub == "") sub = "No Subheading";

  // Initialize objects
  if (result[cat] === undefined) result[cat] = {}; // Empty object
  if (result[cat][sub] == undefined) result[cat][sub] = []; // Empty array

  // Insert element at the position defined by Category on the
  // first layer object, and defined by Subheading on the second layer array
  result[cat][sub].push(obj[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ariel this is amazing! Thanks so much! How would I be able to `.append()` to build out some HTML to pass in the data?